# Readstream on Apache Spark with a bad schema is retrying 1830 times

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

In Spark structured streaming, When the incoming record from S3 doesn't match the schema I enforced with `.schema(..)`, and if the size of the record is large (mine is 397KB), that record is retried exactly 1830 times, tested multiple times. Has anyone noticed this weird behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the s3 object was a json array, and it turns out that spark-s3 json reader processes each entry of the array as an individual record in spark dataframe. So the s3 object had 1830 items, which is why the same s3 object is iterated for 1830 items with errors. However, I could not find any official documentation for this behaviour.